# Threading execution goes slower than sequential

Tags: python, multithreading, dataframe, thread-safety, python-multithreading

I am calculating a measure above a graph, using sequential for every operation takes around 40 seconds, then I need to do this calculation 38 times, a total of 1520 sec or 25min. So, I thought if I use threads this can be faster. I have this template for using threads but I was checking time and I noticed, instead of going faster, this is almost ten times slower.
This lista is a list with the index to use from x_test(test dataset), v_G is a list of graphs, N_exp is the number of times the calculation is performed.

This is sequential code:

```
import time
start1 = time.time()
v_dist1 = []
for i in range(38):
    new_point = X_test[i,:]
    print(new_point)
    
    import time
    start = time.time()
    for G in v_G:
        G1 = add_point(G, new_point)
        # print( nx.adjacency_matrix(G).toarray() )
        v_dist1.append(ant_mod(G1, N_exp))

    # print(v_dist1)

    end = time.time()
    print('time::: ', end - start)
end1 = time.time()
print('time total::: ', end1 - start1)
```

And this the thread code:

```
class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, lista, x_test, v_G, N_exp, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.lista = lista
        self.x_test = x_test
        self.v_G = v_G
        self.N_exp = N_exp
        self.name = name
        
    def run(self):
        pages = []
        # print(self.lista)
        size = len(self.lista)

        for i in range(0,size):
            start = time.time()

            for G in v_G:
                G1 = add_point(G, self.x_test[self.lista[i]])
                pages.append(ant_mod(G1, self.N_exp))
            sleep(0.5)
            end = time.time()
            print('time::: ', end - start)
        data = pd.DataFrame(pages)
        data.to_csv('prueba'+self.name+'.csv', sep ="¬",encoding='utf-8', index=False)
#l[0] is the list with indexes, I use a number of thread equals
#to number of cores-2, then I replicate this code 6 times.
thread1 = myThread(l[0], X_test, v_G, N_exp, str(N_exp)+'.0')
thread1.start()
thread1.join()
```

Comment: How are you using your class? Please [edit] you question and provide a [mre].

Comment: _So, I thought if I use threads this can be faster._ That's not always the case, though. Are you just asking why the code is slower?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I just found the error today, I had a main function then I thought the declared variables only had the scope of this function but some weird reason, one X that I created there was reachable from another function. Besides, I had forgot to add this variable as argument of this function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, **"Multithreading"** is a bit unefficient in **interpreted** programming languages, such as Python or Javascript, because of the **"Global Interpreter Lock / GIL"**.
Thus it will rather slow down your script than improve performance.

Still, that is not a problem when you want to achieve concurrent program execution in order to improve speed, you can use **asynchronous programming** instead in that case.

There's plenty of articles available on the web to that topic **specifically for Python**, so you can just **google it.**

Take care

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I added some details about the problem I have. I am reading about asyncio now.